# Stable Diffusion - Как уменьшить размер файла моделей?

Tags: python, нейронные-сети, искусственный-интеллект

Вероятнее всего я не тут должен задавать подобный вопрос, но нигде в интернете почти нет никакой информации об этом. Если вы знаете, где ещё можно задать подобный вопрос, то напишите пожалуйста.

У меня слабый компьютер и я использую сайт, где можно запускать stable diffusion, но одна из проблем - ограничение в хранилище. Конкретно в моём случае - 5 ГБ на все файлы, включая модель.

Вот одна из моделей в качестве примера, превышающая 5 гб: https://civitai.com/models/7371?modelVersionId=46846 *(SafeTensor)*

Мне её нужно сжать хотя бы до 4.5 ГБ, чтобы оставалось место для всего остального.

Что я могу для этого сделать?

Comment: Для запуска Stable Diffusion можно использовать Google collab там ограничение больше. Вот пример установки: https://dtf.ru/s/595875-neyro-iskusstvo/1607421-ustanovka-stable-diffusion-v-google-colab

Comment: Знаю, но насколько мне известно - там хуже скорость + в последнее врему collab не разрешает использовать их ресурсы для Stable Diffusion. В нём возможна установка модели по прямой ссылке, а не с помощью переноса файла?

Comment: По ссылке которую я скинул можно указать ссылку на модель и она скачается автоматически. Насчёт остального не знаю т.к. сам не пробовал.

Comment: Как я и ожидал - collab постоянно делает сброс, из-за чего очень сложно пользоваться этой нейронкой. Надо ещё где-то вопрос задать, но не знаю где

Comment: Вы можете ещё посмотреть `dstack`: https://dstack.ai/examples/stable-diffusion/